# Getting a txt file in json format using ajax and parsing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, parsing

I need to parse a **txt** file which is stored in a remote server using jquery/Ajax.
It is a text file but written in Json format.
It looks like this:

```
{ 
"id" : "someId",
"title" : "someTitle ",
"data" : ["a","b","c"]
}
```

I need to get the content of the data array. 
Can this be done?

edit:
this is the code im working on.

```
$.ajax({
url : "someURL",
type : 'GET',
data : "json",
success : function(res) {
    $.each(res, function(i, item) {
        console.log(item.title);

    });
},
error : function(data) {
    console.log("error");
}
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @cyk I tried the things in the api and it doesnt work for me. dont forget i use a TXT file ..

Comment: Assuming you've already grabbed the data via ajax, pass it to `JSON.parse()` and assign that to a variable. Then you can access it using dot notation, e.g. `json_txt.data`

Comment: What do you mean by "remote server"? Is the file on the same domain as the one the page is served on? If not you might have a problem with CORS.

Comment: it is not on the same domain.

Comment: @anthonyChu it does do problems with cross domain. Doing locally what you guys said worked. thank you. Is there a way to overcome the cross domain without using php?

Comment: @Vandervidi Use jsonp

Comment: Tried Jsonp. Didnt work in this case. still got CROS errors